# ASIFormDataRequest encoding unicode characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am creating the API data via PHP and it creates unicode characters not correctly.

For example `ü` returned as `\u00fc`

On ASIFormDataRequest I have tried to parsed it correctly but I couldnt manage to do it. What I ve tried so far are:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
[request addRequestHeader:@"content-type" value:@"text/json; charset=utf-8"];
```

I am wondering how can I parse the unicode characters correctly?

Comment: Be aware that `ASIHttpRequest` is deprecated and should not longer be used.

Comment: ü "LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS" is \u00fc in UTF-16. In UTF-8 it is 0xc3 0xbc. There is a mis-match between the character encoding and specifying "charset=utf-8".

Comment: I tried charset=utf-16 also but didnt work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078747/how-do-i-properly-encode-unicode-characters-in-my-nsstring.       See in this first they convert string to data and after apply utf8 encoding

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: set `defaultResponseEncoding` when creating `ASIFormDataRequest`.

```
request.defaultResponseEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
```

Solution 2: set `responseEncoding` before calling `responseString`.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    request.responseEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
    NSLog(@"%@", request.responseString);
}
```